# Stop a php function

Tags: php, function

I have this code that simply validates a date, but ends the script if a error occurs (`exit ()`).

Now i want to put this same code in a single function that returns `false` on error.

I dont want to use "if/else". I want to return `false` on error and stop execution of the others things.

Is that possible?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you could change

```
exit ("Error !");
```

to

```
return false;
```

but exceptions would definitely be better as suggested by Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams

Answer (score 13):

Learn [exceptions](http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php). Live them. Love them.

Comment: Throwing an exception for a non-valid date from a date-verification function seems a bit much...

Comment: Exceptions are useful in weird ways sometimes. I've build a framework that has the procedural equivalent of a ViewModel that gets "included" in each View. If the ViewModel ends up not being able to do what I want it to, rather than hard coding an HTTP abort or redirect response I just run a Closure variable called $redirect(...) or $abort(404, ...) which throws an exception that is caught outside of the include (that way I don't forget to use return or exit to stop the ViewModel) and then passes the instruction to the HTTP response handle. It's a bit hacky but it works well. Fringe case.

Answer (score 3):

I see you already have your answer, but as a side note, are you aware that there is a php function that replaces a big part of your function: [checkdate()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.checkdate.php)

No need for regex's, if statements, etc.